# Jenkins cannot clone submodule via SSH while cmd can

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, bitbucket, git-submodules

**Under Windows 10 cmd**

In windows cmd:

```
git clone https://bbk.example.com/scm/myproject/myrepository.git
cd myrepository
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Everything is fine. Even git submodule via SSH is fine.

The submodule is added under SSH and I want it to be like this.

Here is .gitmodules:

```
[submodule "submodules/validator"]
    path = submodules/validator
    url = ssh://git@bbk.example.com:7999/myproject/validator.git
```

---

Locations:

```
where git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

```
where ssh
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

I set the same git path for Jenkins. And add Jenkins behavior under config, 'Branch Sources':

```
Advanced sub-modules behaviours
- Recursively update submodules: ticked
- Use credentials from default remote of parent repository: ticked
- Path of the reference repo to use during submodule update (empty)
```

Also the behavior option `Checkout over SSH` is added and the SSH credential is added.

---

**Under Jenkins**

When running under Jenkins, it fails with `error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory`:

```
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials userpass
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://bbk.example.com/scm/myproject/myrepository.git +refs/heads/bug/AUTO-534/AUTO-744:refs/remotes/origin/bug/AUTO-534/AUTO-744 # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 2b300d6f20e615894152bdf1aab13efec55eed16 (bug/AUTO-534/AUTO-744)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 2b300d6f20e615894152bdf1aab13efec55eed16 # timeout=10
Commit message: "test"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 2b300d6f20e615894152bdf1aab13efec55eed16 # timeout=10
 > git remote # timeout=10
 > git submodule init # timeout=10
 > git submodule sync # timeout=10
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
 > git submodule init # timeout=10
 > git config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp ^submodule\.(.+)\.url # timeout=10
 > git config --get submodule.submodules/validator.url # timeout=10
 > git remote # timeout=10
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
 > git config -f .gitmodules --get submodule.submodules/validator.path # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials userpass
 > git submodule update --init --recursive submodules/validator # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git submodule update --init --recursive submodules/validator" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into 'C:/ProgramData/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ation-core_bug_AUTO-534_AUTO-744/submodules/validator'...
error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
fatal: clone of 'ssh://git@bbk.example.com:7999/myproject/validator.git' into submodule path 'C:/ProgramData/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ation-core_bug_AUTO-534_AUTO-744/submodules/validator' failed
Failed to clone 'submodules/validator'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'C:/ProgramData/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ation-core_bug_AUTO-534_AUTO-744/submodules/validator'...
error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
fatal: clone of 'ssh://git@bbk.example.com:7999/myproject/validator.git' into submodule path 'C:/ProgramData/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/ation-core_bug_AUTO-534_AUTO-744/submodules/validator' failed
Failed to clone 'submodules/validator' a second time, aborting

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2671)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2096)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$7.lambda$execute$0(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1505)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:323)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService.submit(ExecutorCompletionService.java:184)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.cgit.GitCommandsExecutor.submitRemainingCommand(GitCommandsExecutor.java:98)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.cgit.GitCommandsExecutor.invokeAll(GitCommandsExecutor.java:87)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.cgit.GitCommandsExecutor.checkResult(GitCommandsExecutor.java:110)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.cgit.GitCommandsExecutor.invokeAll(GitCommandsExecutor.java:91)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.cgit.GitCommandsExecutor.invokeAll(GitCommandsExecutor.java:49)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugin
```

---

**Environment**

Jenkins version:

```
java -jar "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --version
2.332.3
```

Plugin: `Bitbucket Server IntegrationVersion` (`3.2.2`)

My system environment variable:

```
GIT_SSH = C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
```

I have enabled SSH via powershell and I want to use it this way:

```
Set-Service -Name ssh-agent -StartupType Manual
Start-Service ssh-agent
ssh-add ~\.ssh\id_rsa
```

I want submodule being downloaded via SSH only even if the main repo is via HTTP.

Note:
Removing the Jenkins behaviors and adding the commands inside the Jenkins

```
sh 'set GIT_SSH=C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe'
sh 'git submodule update --init --recursive'
```

Causes the same error. Even using `/` instead of `\\` does not fix it.

---

**Finally**

How can I fix this error?

```
error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you running Jenkins as a service? If so, then the user account used by Jenkins will be the system service account and that will need configuring for ssh use. It is likely you sorted out your account but not the service account.

Comment: @patthoyts, how can I test it? Running cmd as admin?

Comment: Running commands from `sh` will run them in a subshell. Any variable you change will only change in the subshell, and not affect the parent process (in this case, Jenkins) at all. When the `sh` subprocess exits, all its variables and other state disappears. Also, tangentially, `set` in `sh` does not do at all what you seem to think it does.

Comment: @tripleee, how can I run `sh`? In cmd, I type sh and it is not recognized.

Comment: To run a program, you need to install it properly first. Your problem seems to be rooted in a more basic confusion about the differences between Unix and Windows. If your Jenkins runs on Windows then configure this Windows correctly before starting Jenkins. (Though my bet will always be on abandoning Windows as soon as you can.)

Comment: @mercury, Get [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) and run `psexec -i -s cmd /c start`. The new console will be running as the system user (see `whoami`).

Comment: IIRC there is a Jenkins configuration option where you can configure the location of the SSH binary. I can't recall whether this overrides `GIT_SSH`.

Comment: @patthoyts, from `psexec` I try adding private key. I get `Permissions for 'C:\\ProgramData\\ssh\\id_rsa' are too open` even though I have disabled inherited permission and all access execept for system and administrator. Any advise?

Comment: @patthoyts. Or any way to run jenkins pipelines as a local user?

Comment: If ssh is being a pain, you can use plink from putty using environment variable GIT_SSH=plink. We run Jenkins as a normal user by having a scheduled task that runs on user login that starts the slave process (basically run `java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl someurl -secret somesecret` ). That allows it to make use of the Windows desktop which is useful when doing automated UI testing.

Comment: Would https://superuser.com/q/1296024/141 help regarding permissions?